# Inconsistent performance of code

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm trying to do some optimizations to my code to make it run faster, but it seems that there are inconsistencies in the performance of the code. Namely, the codes have different performance in different execution order.

Here is the original version of the code I try to optimize:

```
TDSESolve1[EE_, energyLs_, diplMtx_, C0_, {tmin_, tmax_, dt_}] :=
 Module[{lth = Length[energyLs], Ht, tls, Ct, Cls, LHS, RHS},
  Ht[t_] := DiagonalMatrix[energyLs] + EE[t]*diplMtx;
  tls = Table[t, {t, tmin, tmax, dt}];
  Ct = C0;
  Cls = Table[
    LHS = IdentityMatrix[lth] + I dt/2 Ht[t + dt/2];
    RHS = (IdentityMatrix[lth] - I dt/2 Ht[t + dt/2]).Ct;
    Ct = LinearSolve[LHS, RHS],
    {t, Most@tls}];
  Prepend[Cls, C0]
  ]
```

In this version, I expanded the `Ht` explicitly:

```
TDSESolve2[EE_, energyLs_List, diplMtx_, C0_, {tmin_, tmax_, dt_}] := 
 Module[{lth = Length[energyLs], Ht, tls, Ct, Cls, LHS, RHS},
  tls = Table[t, {t, tmin, tmax, dt}];
  Ct = C0;
  Cls = Table[
    LHS = 
     DiagonalMatrix[1. + I dt/2 energyLs] + (I dt/2 EE[t + dt/2])*
       diplMtx;
    RHS = Ct - I dt/2 (energyLs*Ct) - (I dt/2 EE[t + dt/2]) diplMtx.Ct;
    Ct = LinearSolve[LHS, RHS],
    {t, Most@tls}];
  Prepend[Cls, C0]
  ]
```

Here are the parameters for the tests:

```
EE[t_] := Sin[t]
dim = 400;
energyLs = RandomReal[{0, 10}, dim];
tmp = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {dim, dim}];
diplMtx = 0.5*(# + Transpose[#]) &@(tmp - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[tmp]]);
C0 = PadRight[{1.}, dim];
tmin = 0.; tmax = 100.; dt = 0.1;
```

When I test these two versions, I get the results that the performance depends on the order of the execution. For example, the `TDSESolve2` is about 2X slower after the execution of `TDSESolve1`:

```
MemoryInUse[]
TDSESolve2[EE, energyLs, diplMtx, C0, {tmin, tmax, dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
MemoryInUse[]
TDSESolve1[EE, energyLs, diplMtx, C0, {tmin, tmax, dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
MemoryInUse[]
TDSESolve2[EE, energyLs, diplMtx, C0, {tmin, tmax, dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
MemoryInUse[]
(* 30233928 *)
(* {6.52668, Null} *)
(* 44830584 *)
(* {18.6517, Null} *)
(* 44832600 *)
(* {13.5754, Null} *)
(* 44830752 *)
```

While if we run `TDSESolve2` repeatedly on a fresh kernel, I get a more consistent performance (with a slow decline of performance):

```
MemoryInUse[]
TDSESolve2[EE, energyLs, diplMtx, C0, {tmin, tmax, dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
MemoryInUse[]
TDSESolve2[EE, energyLs, diplMtx, C0, {tmin, tmax, dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
MemoryInUse[]
TDSESolve2[EE, energyLs, diplMtx, C0, {tmin, tmax, dt}]; // AbsoluteTiming
MemoryInUse[]
(* 47397856 *)
(* {6.45175, Null} *)
(* 47398160 *)
(* {7.37778, Null} *)
(* 47398032 *)
(* {8.85156, Null} *)
(* 47397760 *)
```

So why the performance of `TDSESolve2` declined largely after `TDSESolve1`?

I'm using version 10.3 on OS X 10.11.5.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on 10.4, 10.4.1, OS X 10.11.5; reproduced on 10.3, 10.3.1, OS X 10.11.5